# Error handling, Persistent Container, Notifications IOS

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, notifications, persistent

Hello so I'm building my first app using core data and have project setup questions, I've already followed along to a video and am trying to build a similar app as the demo I watched.

I manually created the core data stack and am not sure how to approach completing the persistentContainer.

I've searched and i am not sure how to log the error to start ( Any place in particular I could look to figure this out)? Secondly I know I need to notify the user if an error occurs and was thinking of approaching the situation as follows:

In the launchScreenViewController file (I'm referring to the first view controller that will appear on the screen for the app opens.

1. embedding the view controller in a navigation controller
2. importing the UserNotifications framework
3. making the launchScreenViewController class conform to the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
4. Adding a variable stored property inside the VC class to hold the access status of the notifications
5. inside view did load requesting authorization as soon as thew app view is loaded

My thought process is this, in order to send an alert/ notification about the persistent store container not working I need to first get access from the user to send notifications correct????

When setting up error handling should I create an enum with all the error options that may occur while trying to initialize the persistent store container? In the app demo we called fatal error but was told not to ship an application this way.

am I heading in the right direction with my though process and set up ?

Answer (score 1):

A more direct way to handle the alert is with the `UIAlertController` and presenting that controller on a failed response from CoreData.

> First create a new empty swift file and copy the following code into it

*I would name it **Alerts+UIViewController***

```
extionsion UIViewController {

    func doFailedAlert(_ message: String, _ error: NSError) { 
         DispatchQueue.main.async { 
             let alert = UIAlertController(title: message, message: "\(error.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert) 
             let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Oh No!", style: .destructive, handler: nil) 
             alert.addAction(action) 
             self.present(alert, animated: true) 
         } 
    } 

}
```

Then from any UIViewController (even nested in a closure) in your app you can call `doFailedAlert("someMessage", someError)` and it will display an alert with your desired message and a description of the error.

When you're ready for deployment you would want to handle the error message differently. The user wont care for those details, but you as a developer will. Having an Enum with all possible errors would be very useful to you, so I would recommend that. You could even use that Enum to give meaningful error messages to your user if an error does occur.